# Run Kestrel on bash on windows

Tags: linux, bash, kestrel-http-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run a simple web site on bash on windows (Windows Anniversary update bash) but I've been so far unsuccessfully.

I'm able to create and run console app, but whenever I type

```
dotnet run
```

on a web project, I get:

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.Check(Int32 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvTcpHandle.GetSockIPEndPoint()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.TcpListenerPrimary.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<>c.<StartAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.ListenerPrimary.<StartAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at WebApplication.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Has anyone been successful in this? Am I asking too much of that "stripped-down-beta linux version"?

**EDIT:**

To reproduce the behavior, on a bash on windows prompt I type:

```
mkdir mytestwebsite
cd mytestwebsite
dotnet new -t web
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

and then the problem appears.

Comment: maybe you can give expert readers some code to work with, as is, you're saying "Its not working" IMHO. Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? Good luck.

Comment: thanks @shellter, edited

Comment: Looks like that port is already in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of that error message is this:

> Error -98 EADDRINUSE address already in use

This is saying that something is already bound to the port you are trying to listen on. For example, if you are trying to run Kestrel and listen on port 80 (the default HTTP port) then Apache may also be already attached. You either need to shut down whatever is already listening on that port or change your app to pick a new port.

Comment: I can't explain who was using the port 5000 (default kestrel port, seems free) but after some random tries with 5001 and 5050 the random "5123" worked. 

So I guess you're right, thanks

Comment: Try running `netstat`, that should list all ports. Not sure if that comes with Bash on Windows...

Comment: already tried, but it shows nothing. tried the same also on the windows host, since they shared the same address, but again no luck. 

It's still a mistery for me but I'm pleased that at least I can run kestrel without virtual machine, sharing the same filesystem etc. It's beta stuff after all